# What’s the difference between esc_html, esc_attr, esc_html_e, and so on?

Tags: functions, escaping

I got feedback from security guy and he pointed out that I should use proper escaping of user input in my code. So I've done some research and found escaping functions.

What’s the difference between them?
When should I use `esc_html()` and when `esc_attr()`?
And when should I use these functions with `_e()` at the end?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/)?

Comment: Yes and that confused me even more :(

Answer (score 49):

**`esc_html()`** escapes a string so that it is not parsed as HTML. Characters like `<` are converted to `&lt;`, for example. This will look the same to the reader, but it means that if the value being output is `<script>` then it won't be interpreted by the browser as an actual script tag.

*Use this function whenever the value being output should not contain HTML.*

**`esc_attr()`** escapes a string so that it's safe to use in an HTML attribute, like `class=""` for example. This prevents a value from breaking out of the HTML attribute. For example, if the value is `"><script>alert();</script>` and you tried to output it in an HTML attribute it would close the current HTML tag and open a script tag. This is unsafe. By escaping the value it won't be able to close the HTML attribute and tag and output unsafe HTML.

*Use this function when outputting a value inside an HTML attribute.*

**`esc_url()`** escapes a string to make sure that it's a valid URL.

*Use this function when outputting a value inside an `href=""` or `src=""` attribute.*

**`esc_textarea()`** escapes a value so that it's safe to use in a `<textarea>` element. By escaping a value with this function it prevents a value being output inside a `<textarea<` from closing the `<textarea>` element and outputting its own HTML.

*Use this function when outputting a value inside a `<textarea>` element.*

`esc_html()` and `esc_attr()` also have versions ending in `__()`, `_e()` and `_x()`. These are for outputting translatable strings.

WordPress has functions, `__()`, `_e()` and `_x()`, for outputting text that can be translated. `__()` *returns* a translatable string, `_e()` *echoes* a translatable string, and `_x()` returns a translatable string with a given context. You've probably seen them before.

Since you can't necessarily trust a translation file to contain safe values, using these functions when outputting a translatable string ensures that the strings being output can't cause the same issue described above.

*Use these functions when outputting translatable strings.*

Comment: Note that by default, there is no difference between `esc_html` and `esc_attr`, the same code is used (they just have a different unused filter): https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/264698/what-is-the-difference-between-esc-html-filter-vs-attribute-escape-filter/264707#264707

Answer (score 10):

`esc_html` would be used inside of html for example between a `<p>` tag

```
<p><?php echo esc_html( $some_variable ); ?></p>
```

`esc_attr` would be used for escaping attribute values on html tags like so:

```
<p my-attribute="<?php echo esc_attr( $some_variable ); ?>"></p>
```

applying `_e` to the end is for using it with text domains and will automatically echo it for you e.g:

```
<p><?php esc_html_e( 'some-text', 'text-domain' ); ?></p>

<p my-attribute="<?php esc_attr_e( 'some-text', 'text-domain' ); ?>"></p>
```

in addition to `_e` there is also `__` which does the same as `_e` but doesnt echo it so you can store it in a variable.

Comment: `_e` is not just for echoing, it's for localisation. So it should only be used when a string is passed to the function, and should include a text domain. Your last example is misusing it.

Comment: @JacobPeattie my bad, i'll update... **EDIT** Fixed